# Sequelize - mongoose like plugins

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sequelize.js

---

I need a way to add `classMethods` and `instanceMethods` to already defined Sequelize model

Something which can be achieved in mongoose using the [Plugins](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) feature

---

I have a model defined for User in models/user.js.

Now, I want to add classMethods like findByUsername, signup, login to this User model BUT within my custom nodejs library.

If Plugins are not supported at the moment, is there any workaround like redefining the User model within the custom library ?

I tried attaching a function directly to the User model using

```
User.findByUsername = User.options.classMethods.findByUsername = function(username, callback) {
    ...
}
```

Which acts like a classMethod and kind of works but I don't think that's the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there isn't any documented way to achieve this (yet), as per mickhansen's comment on github issue [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1125#issuecomment-30574324) the following workarounds work great.

*`classMethod`*

```
User.findByUsername = function(username, callback) {
  ...
}
```

*`instanceMethod`*

```
User.DAO.prototype.authenticate = function(password, callback) {
  ...
}
```